# How to globally change IsolationLevel of all Entity Framework transactions

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am evaluating EF for my next new apps.

How can I globally change the IsolationLevel of all EF transactions in an application?
Ex: Suppose I want to use "Read Committed Snapshot".

While it is OK to specify the IsolationLevel when I explicitely need a TransactionScope anyway (see code below) it would be ugly having to encapsulate every EF save operation in a TransactionScope.

```
 'OK
    Using tsc As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TransactionOption.ReadCommitted)
        UpdateShoppingCart
        EnqueueNewOrder
        SendConfirmationEmail
        tsc.Complete
    End Using

    'Is this really the only way to avoid Serializable?
    Using tsc As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TransactionOption.ReadCommitted)
      _ctx.SaveChanges()
      tsc.Complete
    End Using

    Class TransactionOption
        Public Shared ReadOnly ReadCommitted As New TransactionOptions() With {
            .IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
            .Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout
            }
    End Class
```

I assume mixing IsolationLevles is not a good idea. Am I wrong with that?

With Serializable and SQL Server (in contrast to Oracle) inserting a simple innocent looking read may cause a conversion lock deadlock.

From the EF FAQ:
*"It is recommended that you use READ COMMITTED transactions, and use READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION if you need to have readers not block writers and writers not block readers."*

I do not understand why EF defaults to Serializable and makes it so difficult to change the default isolation level - with SQL Server (in contrast to Oracle's multi-versioning) defaulting to a pessimistic concurrency model. A configuration option  should be very easy to implement - or am I missing something here?

Comment: Where did you find that EF defaults to Serializable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm almost sure that default EF transaction isolation level is based on used database provider. `SaveChanges` executes this code:

```
    ... 
    try
    {
        this.EnsureConnection();
        flag = true;
        Transaction current = Transaction.Current;
        bool flag2 = false;
        if (connection.CurrentTransaction == null)
        {
            flag2 = null == this._lastTransaction;
        }
        using (DbTransaction transaction = null)
        {
            if (flag2)
            {
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            }
            objectStateEntriesCount = this._adapter.Update(this.ObjectStateManager);
            if (transaction != null)
            {
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

As you can see `BeginTransaction` is called without `IsolationLevel` specified. Under the hood it creates provider specific transaction with `IsolationLevel.Unspecified`. Unspecified isolation level should result in default isolation level for database server / driver. In SQL Server default isolation level is `READ COMMITED` so I expect it should use it but I haven't tested it yet.

If you want to globally change isolation level you can override `SaveChanges` in your class derived from `ObjectContext` and wrap `base.SaveChanges()` in custom `TransactionScope`.

Comment: You are correct, my assumption was wrong. Maybe I stumbled into the following problem when testing: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level
I verified that EF's default with SQL Server is "Read Committed" by doing a SqlConnection.ClearAllPools() first and checking with SQLProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a limitation in VB but in C# you would do it like this:

```
 TransactionOptions transactionOptions = GetTransactionOptions();
 new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionOptions)
```

Note that the second parameter is transactionOptions, this can be created as follows:

```
 public TransactionOptions GetTransactionOptions()
    {
        TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        return transactionOptions;
    }
```

By putting the above code in a Factory method, and calling that factory method whenever you need transaction options, you can have one place to change all transaction scopes in your solution.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in the code posted in my question :-) I am looking for a way to not have to enclose each .SaveChanges with a TransactionScope to change EF's default Serializable to Read Committed snapshot.