# Configure IIS web config for my webapi app to use snapshop isolation

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, iis, snapshot-isolation

Due to performance in our system (deadlocks, db reads are locked when db writes are in progress, etc) we want to try out snapshop isolation. I have read about snapshot isolation level, [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/). We use Entity Framework

I have set Snapshop isolation on the db and want to configure our web api apps to use this isolation for both reads and writes. How can I do this? I have read that this can be done in web.config but cannot find how..

Comment: How are you talking to the DB: ADO.NET directly, or via some ORM? (In the latter case: which one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Entity Framework documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx), you need to use a transaction to set the isolation level:

```
using (var tx = myContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot)) {

   // Perform operations on the context...

   await myContext.SaveAsync();
   tx.Commit();
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127370/67392) for details on the defaults: essentially EF uses whatever the database has as its default transaction isolation level via `IsolationLevel.Unspecified`.

Comment: ok so If I have set snapshop isolation level on the db then that is what EF will use? If so does that also apply when using TransactionScope-class in .net

Comment: @JohanLarsson See the linked answer for the first part. You need to RTFM for the second (but I would guess yes).